# Conversion failed in derived table used in vb.net table adapter

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, parameters, casting, derived-table

I'm having a problem when trying to insert parameters into a derived table that is part of my table adapter fill query in a vb.net application.

I'm getting the "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" when I try to use the query in vb.net through the preview window of the Dataset Designer or using the datatableadapter.fill method in my application.

```
SELECT Date, SUM(RegHours) AS RegTotal, SUM(OTHours) AS OTTotal, SUM(VacHours) AS VacTotal, SUM(SickHours) AS SickTotal

FROM (SELECT EmployeeId, Date, RegHours, OTHours, (CASE WHEN TaskId=4 THEN RegHours ELSE NULL END) AS VacHours, (CASE WHEN TaskId=5 THEN RegHours ELSE NULL END) AS SickHours FROM TimeEntry

WHERE (EmployeeId=@EmployeeId) AND (Date>=@StartDate)) AS SubTable

GROUP BY Date
```

The query works perfectly when I have just the @EmployeeId parameter so the issue is with the date conversion.

The query also works fine if I do just the derived table portion:

```
SELECT EmployeeId, Date, RegHours, OTHours, (CASE WHEN TaskId=4 THEN RegHours ELSE NULL END) AS VacHours, (CASE WHEN TaskId=5 THEN RegHours ELSE NULL END) AS SickHours 

FROM TimeEntry 

WHERE (EmployeeId=@EmployeeId) AND (Date>=@StartDate)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the parameters declared as date? How do you fill the parameter value?

Comment: It is filled with the following code, where startdate is a DateTime datatype.    `Me.PayrollTimeSummaryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.RRAPPSDataSet.PayrollTimeSummary, 254, startdate)`. The Date column is configured as a Date type in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by adding the VacHours and StatHours as computed columns in the table definition and then selecting without needing a derived table.

```
SELECT Date, SUM(RegHours) AS TotalReg, SUM(OTHours) AS TotalOT, SUM(VacHours) AS TotalVac, SUM(StatHours) AS TotalStat
FROM TimeEntry
WHERE (EmployeeId = @EmployeeId) AND (Date >= @StartDate) AND (Date <= @EndDate)
GROUP BY Date
```

I suspect I may still not be filling with the correct data type or casting correctly but this did provide a simple solution for me.